# Can't zoom out in visual studio code

Tags: visual-studio-code

I accidentally hit CTRL + = and my IDE is too much zoomed now. I tried the shortcut to zoom out as stated in the official vscode doc, (CTRL + -) but this is not working.

Some help would be appreciated.

Thanks,

Comment: I am having the same problem. I tried control minus on multiple different keyboards including the on-screen keyboard and a numberpad  and it does not work. I cannot even get to view because I can't see it because it is so zoomed in.

Comment: Juste use the keypad from visual keyboard as stated in my self answer ;)

Comment: Not sure what you mean by the visual keyboard I tried the on-screen keyboard in Windows but that didn't work. Here's what I ended up doing which worked for me. I went to the file settings.Json appdata/roaming/code/user and deleted the contents and saved.

Comment: Yup I used the on screen keyboard with the numeric keypad opened and it worked.

Comment: same problem here, have no numeric keypad...

Comment: @Julian just use your on screen keyboard

Comment: thanks, I fixed it with:  CTRL-SHIFT-P, type "reset room", enter

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Found the solution by opening the on-screen keyboard, activating the numeric pad, and using its <kbd>-</kbd>. The <kbd>-</kbd> is not working on my laptop.

Comment: I had to click on the terminal to make it work. If the focus is on the editor it won't work...

Answer (score 60):

On-Screen keyboard did not work for me. But managed to click the `reset zoom` setting under View>Appearance>Reset Zoom.

`Zoom Out` option was not working. However, `Zoom` was reset after clicking `Reset Zoom` option.

Comment: Great. It was difficult to follow any other solution but this worked fine. 
Guys, If you are not able to locate View option, Press ALT+V and work with arrow keys.

Comment: or CTRL-SHIFT-P, type "reset room", enter.

Comment: For the record: this is bad usability.

Answer (score 18):

For that press <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>p</kbd> then type "resetZoom" without inverted commas
its work for me.

Answer (score 7):

On my installation the keyboard shortcuts are working as stated in documentation (<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>-</kbd>). For a workaround you can perhaps use the menu items under `View` > `Zoom Out` as also written in documentation in [Chapter Zoom](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/accessibility#_zoom).

Comment: Did you use the keypad ?

Comment: I used the keypad and the regular key, both work on my machine.

Answer (score 5):

You can reset your zoom by ctrl+0.
By this command your zoom setting will reset

Answer (score 3):

You can try <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>Numpad Subtract</kbd>

Comment: This is actually what I am saying in my accepted answer.

Answer (score 3):

It's simple I just found out, hold **ctrl + -**. This should zoom out and zoom in again just do what you did to zoom in. There are many ways to do it, this is just one of them.

Comment: I stated that this wasn't working in my first post.

Comment: Ok then, you can use ctrl + "+" on your number pad to zoom in, to zoom out use ctrl + "-".

Comment: Please read the whole post before thinking to add more information

Answer (score 2):

I found I had installed the Visual Studio keybindings extension, which conflicted with VS Code.  Removing that extension solved the problem for me.

Alternative you can check your keybindings and re-assign manually.  Ctrl+K then Ctrl+S to open key bindings, where you can search or manually inspect and edit all.

Answer (score 1):

use the ctrl+ or ctrl-which is next to your right not those + and - which is for volume on the top of your keyboard

Answer (score 1):

[Visual Studio Code Linux keyboard shortcuts](https://code.visualstudio.com/shortcuts/keyboard-shortcuts-linux.pdf)   &

[Visual Studio Code Windows keyboard shortcuts](https://code.visualstudio.com/shortcuts/keyboard-shortcuts-windows.pdf)
for zoom in/out:

In My case,

```
in: Ctrl + =
out: Ctrl + -
```

Answer (score 0):

ctrl+shift+j then search zoom then click view : zoom out

Answer (score 0):

step 1.open setting.json after u comand to zoom and looking eror
step 2.in setting json

- search "window.zoomLevel"
- delete "window.zoomLevel" or change value in "window.zoomLevel": 0
- save setting.json
  i hope this work to you

Answer (score 0):

Zoom-in   : `Left-click` 
Zoom-out : `Left-click + Ctrl`

Answer (score 0):

1. You might have to open setting by going: ⌘,
2. Then search up zoom
3. click the first checkbox on.
4. now you can zoom by hitting ⌘ then scrolling

Answer (score 0):

The keyboard commands may not work when you are focused on an editor if there are conflicting commands attached to plugins for your editor (for example my python plugin uses that command to expand or close functions). But the commands should still work when you click the side bar or the terminal.

You have two options:

1. Remove plugins or adjust your shortcut settings to prevent editor plugins from overriding those shortcuts. I can't be more specific about this without knowing your plugins.
2. Use the command to jump to the terminal and back (it is the one command to jump back and forth, windows: ctrl + j, mac: cmd +j) before and after you zoom.

Answer (score 0):

on Mac.
Menu bar > View > Appearance > Reset Zoom

On an image file within vscode, zoom in with 'click' and zoom out with 'Option-click'

Answer (score 0):

For azerty keyboards with no numpads, ctrl + "-" is detected as "ctrl + 6" when recording keys. However VS Code seems to interpret it as synonymous to "ctrl + -" when looking for existing keybindings.
[image: searching for ctrl + 6 gives ctrl + - too]

Somehow, zooming out still didn't work despite the shortcut being set up on "ctrl + -", and rerecording the shortcut did fix it despite not actually changing they keybinding.

The value displayed is for the keybinding is still "ctrl + -" rather than "ctrl + 6" but now it works.

Tested on 1.85.