# How to reset VS Code's window zoom setting?

Tags: visual-studio-code

While changing VS Code's "windows zoom" setting, I accidentally changed the zoom setting to 10, so now it is zoomed so much that I can't change it to default.

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can't zoom out in visual studio code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53696119/cant-zoom-out-in-visual-studio-code)

Comment: I have this bug too - I can increase the size of everything with Ctrl+= but Ctrl+- and Ctrl+0 don't do anything.

Comment: See also: [How to change font size in VS Code sidebar?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51456526/4561887)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### VSCode window zoom for *all windows and editors:* zoom in and out, reset zoom, use fractional values

The Window zoom settings affect *all* GUI elements in VSCode, including the editor, the sidebar, the status bar, the command palette, the settings, etc. This setting shows up in the settings.json file as `"window.zoomLevel": 0,`, for example. **It affects *all* open VSCode Windows.** If you'd just like to zoom in and out in this window's editor only, see the section below on "Editor font size zoom" instead.

You can zoom in and out with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>+</kbd> (technically <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>=</kbd>), and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>-</kbd>, respectively.

But, that doesn't tell you where your *default* zoom level is exactly. To reset back to the *default* zoom level in a single go, there are three ways:

1. If you have a numpad on your keyboard (I don't): <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>NumPad0</kbd>
2. From the command menu: press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>P</kbd> to enter the command menu, then search for "View: Reset Zoom", and select it.
3. Open your user `settings.json` file by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>P</kbd> and then searching for "Preferences: Open User Settings (JSON)". Find your `"window.zoomLevel"` and set it to `"window.zoomLevel": 0,`.

Your zoom will be back to default.

If you're editing your user `settings.json` file directly (located at `~/.config/Code/User/settings.json` on Linux, by the way), here are a few more possible values for it, to help you gain understanding:

```json
// zoomed out 8 levels (this is the minimum zoom)
"window.zoomLevel": -8,


// zoomed out one level
"window.zoomLevel": -1,

// default zoom level
"window.zoomLevel": 0,

// zoomed in one level
"window.zoomLevel": 1,


// zoomed in 8 levels (this is the maximum zoom)
"window.zoomLevel": 8,
```

As you manually zoom in and out with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>+</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>-</kbd>, you can see this setting change. When you get to the default zoom level of `0`, it will remove the setting entirely, since that's the default zoom level.

You can open the default settings file to see *all* default settings by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>P</kbd> and then searching for "Preferences: Open Default Settings (JSON)".

In there you'll see this for the window zoom level. Notice that the explanation says you can also use zoom decimals for finer granularity (ex: `"window.zoomLevel": 0.5`):

```json
// Adjust the zoom level of the window. The original size is 0 and each
// increment above (e.g. 1) or below (e.g. -1) represents zooming 20% larger or
// smaller. You can also enter decimals to adjust the zoom level with a finer
// granularity.
"window.zoomLevel": 0,
```

### Editor font size zoom (*separate for each open Window* in VSCode)

If you have multiple windows of VSCode open, you can adjust the font size zoom *only for this one window* by using the `Editor Font Zoom` commands instead. Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>P</kbd> to enter the command menu, then search for `Editor Font Zoom`, and select one of the three options below:

1. `Editor Font Zoom In`
2. `Editor Font Zoom Out`
3. `Editor Font Zoom Reset`

...as shown here:

[image]

These do *not* create a new setting entry inside `settings.json`. Instead, they just change the font size of the editor in the current window, allowing you to have different font sizes in different windows.

This is very useful when you have multiple monitors with different resolutions, and you want to have a different font size on each monitor. You may need to set the Window zoom which affects all windows to meet your needs on the main monitor, but then adjust the font zoom only on the secondary monitor to make it look right. I have a 4k 32" main monitor with a huge resolution of 3840 x 2160, making everything on it tiny, and a really old monitor with a tiny resolution of 1280 x 1024, making everything on it look huge. Now, I can use `Editor Font Zoom Out` repeatedly on the old monitor to make it zoom out enough that it's usable and still provides a really good size editor window.

You can also **set keyboard shortcuts for these commands** in your `keybindings.json` file. We will add these shortcuts:

1. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>=</kbd> = `Editor Font Zoom In`
2. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>-</kbd> = `Editor Font Zoom Out`
3. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>0</kbd> = `Editor Font Zoom Reset`

Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>P</kbd> to enter the command menu, then search for `Preferences: Open Keyboard Shortcuts (JSON)` to open your `keybindings.json` file. Then, add these entries:

```
[
    // ... other keybindings here, then add:

    {
        "key": "ctrl+shift+=",
        "command": "editor.action.fontZoomIn"
    },
    {
        "key": "ctrl+shift+-",
        "command": "editor.action.fontZoomOut"
    },
    {
        "key": "ctrl+shift+0",
        "command": "editor.action.fontZoomReset"
    }
]
```

Save the file and close it, and now you can use the 3 new shortcuts above.

---

That's everything I know about VSCode zoom.

### See also

1. [How to change font size in VS Code sidebar?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55324691/4561887)
2. Get all of my VSCode settings in my [eRCaGuy_dotfiles](https://github.com/ElectricRCAircraftGuy/eRCaGuy_dotfiles) repo here:

   1. [`~/.config/Code/User/settings.json`](https://github.com/ElectricRCAircraftGuy/eRCaGuy_dotfiles/blob/master/home/.config/Code/User/settings.json)
   2. [`~/.config/Code/User/keybindings.json`](https://github.com/ElectricRCAircraftGuy/eRCaGuy_dotfiles/blob/master/home/.config/Code/User/keybindings.json)

Answer (score 7):

There are two types of zooms in VS Code:

- **Window zoom level:** to reset, use Ctrl+Numpad0
- **Editor font zoom level:** to reset, press Ctrl+Shift+P, search "Editor Font Zoom Reset". That's your guy.

Comment: In my VS Code (v1.86), I the command to reset the editor font zoom level is "Reset Editor Font Size". That's the one I need after doing a Ctrl + Mouse Scroll Whell Zoom.

Answer (score 4):

click the reset zoom setting under View>Appearance>Reset Zoom.Otherwise you can use the hotkey which is (CTRL + -).

Comment: Actually I can't scroll or move the cursor anywhere.

Comment: hotkey not working?

Comment: No I tried ctrl+, ctrl-, ctrl 0, but nothing happens

Comment: Is there any way to reset all settings with keyboard

Comment: %APPDATA%\Code\User\settings.json deleting this file might do

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

You can do `Ctrl` + `-` to dezoom.

Answer (score 0):

Go to this path `C:\Users\<your admin name>\AppData\Roaming\Code\User`

then open the settings file with any text editor at the end of the file change the  window.zoomLevel to  0

after changing :

```
"window.zoomLevel": 0
```

Answer (score -1):

Use (Ctrl+-) to zoom out. Its simple you can google it as well

https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/accessibility

Comment: I did it but it is not changing

Comment: Try this by switching numlock on 'Ctrl+Numpad0'

Comment: It will reset the zoom

Comment: I tried but no effect

Comment: Did you switch on the Numlock

Comment: dont press + just press ctrl and 0

Comment: I did the same but no effect

Comment: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/how-to-quickly-change-the-zoom-level-for-magnifier-07411e2a-349b-1ca0-7109-3d0f07f11edd

Comment: Try this out press and hold Windows logo key  + Minus sign